# List all Posts under heading in wp_list_pages menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently using the default Page Navigation (wp_list_pages) with wordpress and I have set my homepage to a page called "Home" and my blog to a page called "Events" but I would like to list the 10 most recent posts under the child of "Events".

I attempted to hack it in using the following code but it threw up content all over the place and removed tags:

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'add_forum_link');
function add_forum_link($output) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="#">Blog</a><ul>';

        query_posts('showposts=10');
        while ( have_posts() ){ the_post();

        $output .= '<li><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
        }

        $output .= '</ul></li>';
        echo $output;
}
```

Plus it involved me creating a new link called "Events" and so it doesn't work very well.

Is there an option to just make Wordpress find which page I've set as my Posts and show the last 10 blog posts under that heading?

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Use WP_Query instead of query posts,

Also, you cannot list the posts listing under a page name (heading). Because a post is not related to a page. So either you need to keep the page name as a category and list the post of particular category.

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'add_forum_link');
function add_forum_link($output) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="#">Blog</a><ul>';

        $query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 10,'post_type' => 'post'));

        while (  $query->have_posts() ){  $query->the_post();

        $output .= '<li><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
        }

        $output .= '</ul></li>';
        echo $output;
}
```

//Or else if yu need to list all post under category events, then use this, but you need to add category with name "events"

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'add_forum_link');
function add_forum_link($output) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="#">Blog</a><ul>';

        $query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 10,'post_type' => 'post','category_name' => 'events'));

        while (  $query->have_posts() ){  $query->the_post();

        $output .= '<li><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
        }

        $output .= '</ul></li>';
        echo $output;
}
```